# Swift/iOS: Subclassing UILabel and setting properties

Tags: object-oriented, swift, ios

I'm writing this subclass to add an icon to a UILabel. It works, but I'm wondering if this is the best/cleanest way to do it. Do you see any improvements? Should maybe `text` and `image` properties be set using a `init()` method?

```
import UIKit

class IconLabel: UILabel {

    override var text: String? {
        set {
            nameLabel.text = newValue
        }
        get {
            return nameLabel.text
        }
    }

    var image: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            icon.image = image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        }
    }

    private lazy var icon: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.tintColor = .white
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return imageView
    }()

    private lazy var nameLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.font = Theme.regular(size: .tiny)
        return label
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.backgroundColor = Theme.supportLightGrayColor
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        self.clipsToBounds = true
        self.addSubviewsAndConstraints()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private func addSubviewsAndConstraints() {
        self.addSubview(icon)
        self.addSubview(nameLabel)

        self.directionalLayoutMargins = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 5.0, leading: 5.0, bottom: 5.0, trailing: 5.0)

        icon.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.layoutMarginsGuide.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        icon.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        icon.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.layoutMarginsGuide.heightAnchor).isActive = true
        icon.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: icon.heightAnchor).isActive = true

        nameLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: icon.rightAnchor, constant: 5.0).isActive = true
        nameLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: icon.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        nameLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.layoutMarginsGuide.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `IconLabel` to act as a container, it contains another `UILabel` and `UIImageView`. There is no need that `IconLabel` should be a `UILabel` you can just have your label `nameLabel` and your imageView `icon` in a `UIView` container. It means that you need to change :

`class IconLabel: UILabel {`

to something like

`class IconLabelView: UIView {`

another note, to keep your custom view generic it's better that you setup the background color outside the class like :

```
let customView = IconLabelView()
customView.backgroundColor = Theme.supportLightGrayColor
```

also I think it's better to have two methods for the subview setup and constraints instead of one:

`private func addSubviews()`

and

`private func addConstraints()`